# iphone - A good json framework

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, json

I've been using SBJson to parse json on my project.
But this framework has way too many leaks.
Is there a better framework/Library I can use to parse json?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best JSON library to use when developing an iPhone application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/286087/best-json-library-to-use-when-developing-an-iphone-application)

Comment: Puh-lease, countless versions of this question has been asked and answered on SO before. Complete waste of everyone's time.

Comment: I don't see any bug reports about leaks from you. Please demonstrate what leaks you are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

What about: https://github.com/schwa/touchcode.

Comment: It is perhaps better? They offer a JSON parser? See question?

Answer (score 0):

iOS 5.1 has a built-in json library. You can use nsjsonserialization